# Does (ceiling function of -x) = - (floor function of x) holds true for all x belongs to R?

Tags: functions

> Does $$\lceil -x\rceil = -\lfloor x\rfloor$$ hold true $\forall x\in\mathbb R$? Give reasons for your answer. Prove it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What definition of the floor and roof function are you working with and have you tried comparing them with the identity?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=n+f$ with $n$ integer and $0\le f<1$.

$$\lceil -n-f\rceil=-\lfloor n+f\rfloor$$ can be simplified to

$$-n+\lceil-f\rceil=-n+\lfloor f\rfloor$$ or
$$\lceil-f\rceil=\lfloor f\rfloor$$

and this is $$0=0.$$

Comment: Here, n should be n = ⌊x⌋. Is it right?

Comment: @RatneshKumarSharma: sorry, I forgot to mention $n$ integer.